# Installing windows 7 - no Disk Space

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation, upgrade

So I tried installing/upgrading my HP Compaq (fully sufficient specs) running Vista Home Edition to Windows 7.

I continuously get the error for upgrade that `No disk space is available` and if I try a fresh install (x64/x86) then I get `No hard drive found`.

At first it had an OEM partition, so I used easeUS to merge the partition to the C:/ drive, yet still got the problem (bear in mind I have 110gb free). So then I tried splitting into two partitions, one half having 110gb (20 free) and the over 90gb. However I still get the same problem, no matter what I try.

I think this may be quite an old version of W7..

Comment: Are you using the same disk for upgrade/fresh? Sort of scary about no hard drive found if this is the same disk.

Comment: planning on dualbooting or just 7?

Comment: Just windows 7 install ... using the same disk. It's definitely there, the OS see's it, hardware manager see's it, I havent checked the bios yet but easeUS saw it as well..

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with your partition table. Try burning [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) to a CD, then boot the computer to it. It will bring up a GUI. Delete the partitions (**WARNING, THIS WILL DELETE ALL DATA FROM THE DRIVE** Only advanced recovery software will be able to get your data back from this state, if at all.). Then try installing Windows 7 again. It will see it as a blank drive and shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to use the manufacturer's recovery CD to recover your OS... or slipstream the drivers for your disk controller directly into your windows 7 install disk.  You might be able to get lucky and go into the bios and change your disk controller "mode" to emulate a different mode which will let you install 7... and then after getting the proper drivers installed... switch it back.